# How to apply Xib width conditionally based on device width?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, xib

how to fix the width of Xib based on device width? .I have created custom navigation bar with xib view ? but i am facing problem with width of the xib ? 
`func loadNavigation() {

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(customNavigation.view)
    customNavigation.leftBtn?.isHidden = false
    customNavigation.rightBtn?.isHidden = false
    customNavigation.titleLbl?.isHidden = false
    customNavigation.titleLbl?.text = NSLocalizedString("Teacher Profile", comment: "")
    customNavigation.leftBtn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PTeacherProfileViewController.BackAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    customNavigation.rightBtn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PTeacherProfileViewController.DownAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
}`
```

this is the way i am using navigation bar

Comment: Please post some code. Show us what you tried.

Comment: Please let us know, how you wrote the code. So that we can easily help out

Comment: that is the function i am using in all classes , simply i taken xib file to for navigation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
view.frame.size.width =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

Comment: Probably because it's a code-only answer or it doesn't work. While it might be self explanatory to some, it's always better to explain how/why this piece of code works and how is it relevant to the question.